# Redactor table plugin for craft

Tags: plugins, redactor

Okay so my question is simple. Is there a craft plugin that lets me add tables in my redactor fields? If not then is there a way I can add the table.js to the redactor plugin config. I add ti but it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Craft ships with Redactor’s [Table plugin](https://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/table/), but you must add it to your Redactor config yourself (in craft/config/redactor/).

```
{
    // ...
    plugins: ['table']
}
```

To determine which config file to place this in, go to your field’s settings in Settings → Fields → [your Rich Text field name], and check your “Redactor Config” setting.

Comment: I do this on all my sites - just edit the redactor config, no problem.

Comment: WHEN Craft updates to Redactor 10 this MIGHT break. Redactor changelog states that [Tables is now in a separate plugin](http://imperavi.com/redactor/log/).

Comment: Hey Guys thank you for all your responses. I was confused since just adding it did not work for me at first and neither did it work for a collegue of mine. But later on adding it in the config json simply solved the problem.

Comment: Craft 2.3.2615 comes with Redactor 10.0.5. It's no longer enough to add 'table' to your buttons. You need to add the plugin as I wrote in [my answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/3029/125), @MoinQidwai.

Comment: Yes, to clarify, you currently add it to your Redactor config plugins line, like: `plugins: ['fullscreen', 'table'],`.

Comment: This also works for craft 3. yay! "plugins": ["table"]